# How to implement circular buffer where data to be written to the buffers is an RTSP stream from camera?

Tags: android, c++, camera, rtsp, openrtsp

I have a camera which is streaming data in h.264 format. 
I want to implement circular buffer. The content of each buffer will be RTSP stream from camera.
Question is - How to save camera streaming data to the circular buffer? later upon certain operation we will save this data to the Hard Disk.

Could anybody please support? I want to implement this in C++.